# Not able to add a WebPart in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

We are using SharePoint Online. Once I try to add a new WebPart by editing the page, it doesn't allow me to do so. I try to click on the "Add a Web Part" button but nothing happens[image] Please see screenshot attached. I tried using different browsers like Chrome and Firefox but it didn't work. I have also attached the output from the Web Browser Console.

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
Home.aspx
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/style%20library/intranet365/content/editor/ck/ckeditor.js
Home.aspx (42,1)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/style%20library/intranet365/content/editor/ck/adapters/jquery.js
Home.aspx (43,1)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/ignite.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_normalize.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/_mixins.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/_settings.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_base.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_components.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_base-font-icons.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_base-links.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_layout.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_base-sp-overrides.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/base/_base-typography.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_grid.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_master.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_home.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_dept-home.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_col-templates.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_doc-library.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/layout/_library-list.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-announcements.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-banner.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-content-block.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-dept-nav.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-buttons.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-control-header.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-calendar.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-discussion-board.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-document-list.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-document-filters.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-discussion-thread.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-event-detail.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-discussion-summary.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-document-summary.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-folder-tree.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-libList.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-quicklinks.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-event-summary.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-search-combo.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-tabs.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-top-nav.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-transformer-tabs.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-traffic.scss
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/Style%20Library/sass/components/_ia-weather.scss
HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
Home.aspx (126,176)
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
Home.aspx (163,5)
HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.
Home.aspx (459,19)
HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.
Home.aspx (460,19)
HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.
Home.aspx (461,19)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/_catalogs/masterpage/Ignite/HYPERLINK%20%22http:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic
Theming: (404) /sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/_catalogs/masterpage/Ignite/HYPERLINK "http:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic
theming.js (1,12456)
SCRIPT5009: 'CKEDITOR' is undefined
ak.addin.snippet.js (918,9)
SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.
Home.aspx
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/style%20library/intranet365/js/ak.addin.discussions.joined.js
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
util.js (211,33)
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
GET - https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?httpCode=500&ts=131267272706568011&be=SN1PR14MB0525&authError=OpenIdConnect OpenIdConnectException&rt=Form15&fe=BN6PR14CA0014&dag=NAMPR14DG033&forest=namprd14.prod.outlook.com&reqid=420b516a-80c1-4137-b0b8-c8b0acddc038&msg=InvalidIdToken
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/errorFE.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/owa/plt1.ashx&off=0&PLT=now,0&msg=FormErr
HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
GET - https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=rr%40sohodragon.com&suiteServiceReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsohodragon.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FIndianMotorcyclesAkumina%2FPages%2FHome.aspx&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsohodragon.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FIndianMotorcyclesAkumina%2FPages%2FHome.aspx&Silent=1
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/forbidframingedge.htm
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/Assets/ErrorPages/httpErrorPagesScripts.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/ErrorPageStyles.css
theming.js (1,12456)SCRIPT5009: 'CKEDITOR' is undefinedak.addin.snippet.js (918,9)SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.Home.aspxHTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).(XHR)GET - https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com/sites/IndianMotorcyclesAkumina/style%20library/intranet365/js/ak.addin.discussions.joined.jsGoogle Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keysutil.js (211,33)HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.GET - https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?httpCode=500&ts=131267272706568011&be=SN1PR14MB0525&authError=OpenIdConnect OpenIdConnectException&rt=Form15&fe=BN6PR14CA0014&dag=NAMPR14DG033&forest=namprd14.prod.outlook.com&reqid=420b516a-80c1-4137-b0b8-c8b0acddc038&msg=InvalidIdTokenHTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.(XHR)GET - https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/errorFE.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/owa/plt1.ashx&off=0&PLT=now,0&msg=FormErrHTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.GET - https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=rr%40sohodragon.com&suiteServiceReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsohodragon.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FIndianMotorcyclesAkumina%2FPages%2FHome.aspx&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsohodragon.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FIndianMotorcyclesAkumina%2FPages%2FHome.aspx&Silent=1SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/forbidframingedge.htmSEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/Assets/ErrorPages/httpErrorPagesScripts.jsSEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/ErrorPageStyles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the permissions of the webpart gallery at your site collection root:

https://sitecollectionroot/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: I tried checking the permissions but it didn't help.

Comment: @user3402248, but, you have permisssions? When you select your webpart, did you see any alert or error(s). Also check if your webpart doesn't not have errors and if its features are active. Please edit your question with the results.

Comment: @Mauricio I am not able to add a "new" Webpart to the page because when I click on the button "Add a Webpart" it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user3402248 please press F12 and check the `console` and `network` tabs, try again and check if there are errors.

Comment: @user3402248 may be you have some JavaScript code, which is stopping you from adding new web part. Like Mauricio suggested check for error using browser console.

Comment: @Maurico I get a list of HTTP404: The server has not found anything matching the requested URI, 'CKEDITOR' is undefined, The Server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling your request.

Comment: @Mauricio I have updated the post with the Output from the Console.

Comment: @user3402248 Is the stuff in your style library checked in and published?

Comment: @user3402248, also check this: try select another webpart (_native or one that you created_) and check if you can add it to your page, if all this fails, probably the problem is **your** webpart.

Comment: @ArinZandbergen Yes the Style Library is checked in and published.

Comment: @Mauricio I can edit Existing webparts on this page. But I cannot add a **new** WebPart since nothing happens when I click the **Add a Web Part** button.

Comment: @user3402248, please try add it again and check the logs. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525197/where-is-the-default-log-location-for-sharepoint-moss) about logs location.

Comment: @Maurico I am using SharePoint Online, and I believe we don't have access to logs. Central Administration is only for SharePoint Servers.